# HTML data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I use `data-field` in JavaScript?

```
<button onclick="btn()" data-field= "{ i: thevalueofi, j: tthevalueofj }"></button>
<script>
    function btn(){
        ???
        alert("data-field");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779451/html-element-with-variable